# jQuery get contents to closest H3 tag

Tags: jquery, html, dom

I'm trying to get the content of a H3 tag closest to my selected element.

```
$(this).closest('h3').html();
```

The code above contains null when run, "this" is definitely the selector of another element in the same parent element as the h3.

Can someone offer an idea as to why it won't work?

Thanks.

Comment: please provide an example fiddle

Comment: Have you checked if `closest` returns something?

Comment: can you let us know what `element` have you used, and you can try jsfiddle.net for online..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> "this" is definitely the selector of another element **in the same
>   parent element**

That's your problem. `closest` looks *up* the DOM tree, not along it at siblings. Use [`siblings`](http://api.jquery.com/siblings/) instead:

```
$(this).siblings('h3').html();
```

Note that this will return the HTML of the first `h3` sibling. If there are more you will probably want to specify the correct one.

Comment: You're right. It was that. I needed to use parent too, I forgotten about a fieldset. This is what I've used, $(this).parent('fieldset').siblings('h3').html(); which works perfectly. Thank you. I'll accept when I can.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery also has the methods `.next()` and `.prev()`, just in case you know which direction the `h3` is in relation to `$(this)`.

For example:

```
$(this).click(function(){
    $(this).next('h3').html('a string');
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I'm pretty new to transversing HTML in jQuery, next() and prev() sound great, too.